# Can we take a property of Map as a sort/range key be in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Lets suppose I have the following JSON

```
{  
  "id": "ads",
  "model": "PS-19213",
  "trips": [
    {
      "time": {
        "startTime": "2016-11-08T14:59:07.198Z",
        "endtime": "2016-11-08T15:01:01.132Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have taken property 'id' as a partition key. My question is can I take the property of a map as a sort/range key in dynamoDB i.e. trips[0].time.startTime as a sort key. Although I know whole map can't be a sort key but property of map is itself scalar.

Answer (score 10):

The Partition/Sort Key must be a a scalar element (String, Number, or Binary).

> A KeySchemaElement must be a scalar, top-level attribute (not a nested
>   attribute). The data type must be one of String, Number, or Binary.

You can't create indexes on Document (i.e. Map and List) data type as well.

[Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeySchemaElement.html)